# Pagination - Display Java Query results gradually

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

If I have a query result of 50 elements and I want to create a button in my jsp page which show this result a bit a time..How can I solve it?
Thanks

Comment: The topic you want to search on is called "pagination".

Comment: Can you suggest me some links?Thanks

Comment: http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many libraries out there which do pagination for JSPs or for HTML pages.

Here is one: [DisplayTag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/)